# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. when trying to return a single value from LINQ query

Tags: linq-to-sql

The following code examples both result in this run-time error:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
var venuename = (from v in db.Venues
where v.PropGroupID.Equals(propgroup)
select v.VenueName).SingleOrDefault();


var venuename = (from v in db.Venues
where v.PropGroupID.Equals(propgroup)
select v.VenueName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Removing "SingleOrDefault()" (or FirstOrDefault) results in this compile-time error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'

```
var venuename = (from v in db.Venues
where v.PropGroupID.Equals(propgroup)
select v.VenueName);
```

I want to return the text from the field VenueName (it is in SQL Server DB with data type = nvarchar(75)).  PropGroupID is currently unique (but that is not enforced).  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from:

```
var venueName = db.Venues
                    .Where(x => x.PropGroupId.Equals(propgroup))
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.VenueName);
```

About removing the "FirstOrDefault", you can get more information about lazy loading:

- [Entity Framework Loading Related
  Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)
- [LINQ    To Entities and Lazy

  Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338986)